# Draw view before screen off or while screen off

Tags: android

**Target**: *sleep screen* for e-ink device.

**Setup**: e-ink device with android 4.4.2, firmware sources not available.

**What I've tried already**:

---

1) Overlay with zero brightness

> 1. add receiver for android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF/android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON;
> 2. on screen off add fullscreen view in WindowManager with flags 'FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON', 'FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON' and brightness set to '0';

Problems: device is not sleeping since screen is on, flicker since we're preventing device from going to sleep;

---

2) Simulate POWER_KEY press

> 1. add receiver for android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF/android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON;
> 2. start fullscreen activity with flag 'FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON';
> 3. after activity is started simulate send POWER_KEY press with 'input keyevent 26';

Problems: root needed, flicker since we're preventing device from going to sleep;

---

**What I want**:

Solution that will not require root and will put device to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second thought - it seems not quite possible as it is.

Because, looking at the logs I saw that SurfaceFlinger is releasing screen before ActivityManager displays my activity. So, activity is actually get rendered it's just the screen won't update since system already received sleep-signal.

Maybe this could be figured out with NDK and fw sources.